# converting numpy array into dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have an array like the following:

```
[( 1, b'"C"'), ( 2, b'"C#"'), ( 3, b'"D"'), ( 4, b'"D#"'),
 ( 5, b'"E"'), ( 6, b'"F"'), ( 7, b'"F#"'), ( 8, b'"G"'),
 ( 9, b'"G#"'), (10, b'"A"'), (11, b'"A#"'), (12, b'"B"'))]
```

I want to convert this to a dictionary "d" such that when I say
`d[11]` I will get `"A#"`.

EDIT: learnt that dict is a reserved word, so I changed it to "d".

Comment: and what did you try that failed?

Comment: Being a beginner to Python/numpy  I wanted to learn how I convert a two-dimensional array to a dictionary where column 1 is the key and column 2  the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list1 = [( 1, b'"C"'), ( 2, b'"C#"'), ( 3, b'"D"'), ( 4, b'"D#"'),
       ( 5, b'"E"'), ( 6, b'"F"'), ( 7, b'"F#"'), ( 8, b'"G"'),
       ( 9, b'"G#"'), (10, b'"A"'), (11, b'"A#"'), (12, b'"B"')]

dict1 = {a : b for a,b in list1}

print(dict1)
{1: '"C"', 2: '"C#"', 3: '"D"', 4: '"D#"', 5: '"E"', 6: '"F"', 7: '"F#"', 8: '"G"', 9: '"G#"', 10: '"A"', 11: '"A#"', 12: '"B"'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be asking for a dict where the value is a Unicode string.  If that's the case then you need to decode it and remove the extra quotes.  This would do that although my interpreter defaults to echo strings with single quotes rather than double.

```
mydict = {k: v.decode().replace('"', "") for k, v in list1}
```

and the result is:

```
{1: 'C', 2: 'C#', 3: 'D', 4: 'D#', 5: 'E', 6: 'F', 7: 'F#', 8: 'G', 9: 'G#', 10: 'A', 11: 'A#', 12: 'B'}
```

That uses a dict comprehension to loop over the list with decode converting from byte to unicode.  Replace can be removed if you wish to retain the inner quotes.

You don't want to call a dict, dict so I've used mydict.

Comment: This didn't address my actual problem but nice idiom to learn and useful.

Comment: That's cool.  FYI, if all you required was the conversion you ticked, there is a simpler way - just use `dict(list1)` as this will convert your list of tuples to a dict.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
    numpy_arr = [( 1, b'"C"'), ( 2, b'"C#"'), ( 3, b'"D"'), ( 4, b'"D#"'),
           ( 5, b'"E"'), ( 6, b'"F"'), ( 7, b'"F#"'), ( 8, b'"G"'),
           ( 9, b'"G#"'), (10, b'"A"'), (11, b'"A#"'), (12, b'"B"')
           ]

    dictonry = dict(numpy_arr)
    print(dictonry)
    print(dictonry[11])
```

Comment: OutPut:
{1: b'"C"', 2: b'"C#"', 3: b'"D"', 4: b'"D#"', 5: b'"E"', 6: b'"F"', 7: b'"F#"', 8: b'"G"', 9: b'"G#"', 10: b'"A"', 11: b'"A#"', 12: b'"B"'}

b'"A#"'

Answer (score 0):

A general way:

```
>     A = np.random.randint(0,10,(3,3))
```

([[5, 0, 8],[3, 0, 5],[0, 4, 4]])

```
>     B = dict(zip(A[:,0],A[:,1:]))
```

{5: array([0, 8]), 3: array([0, 5]), 0: array([4, 4])}

with the first column as keys